# Scoreboard Currency

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm trying to create a map in Minecraft Bedrock PE and I want to know how to test for players with a minimum score for a store. My score currency name is Buckz. I tried "testfor @p [score_Buckz_min=~] but that doesn't work in my version. Does anyone know how to do this in Minecraft Bedrock 1.11.0 on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

try `testfor @p[scores={Buckz=10..}]`

This should check if there is a player with at least 10 Buckz

It is important to use the name and NOT the display name!

[See here for more information on the `/scoreboard` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard)